# JavaScript - HTML5 data attributes

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I've looked around on the web for an answer to my question. Found lots of scripts that I've copied and messed around with but can't get it working properly.

When I run it, my script below initially works but then displays 'NaN'.

I'm trying to create a simple order form that uses JavaScript to dynamically update and display the order total.

Each item for sale has an input (type=number) tag that contains the item's price in a 'data-price' attribute.

What I'm trying to do is grab the price out of the data-price attribute and use it in a JS script to display a total.

Users can enter a quantity into text field and the TOTAL text field should automatically update with correct 'running total'.

Would appreciate any advice as to where I'm going wrong. I've used JavaScript (as opposed to jQuery) because I'm more familiar with the syntax.

```
<script>

function calculateTotal(frm) {
var order_total = 0

for (var i=0; i < frm.elements.length; ++i) {

    form_field = frm.elements[i];

    item_price = form_field.dataset.pric);

    item_quantity = form_field.value;

        if (item_quantity >= 0) {
            order_total += item_quantity * item_price;
        }
}

frm.total.value = round_decimals(order_total, 2);
}

function round_decimals(original_number, decimals) {
var result1 = original_number * Math.pow(10, decimals);
var result2 = Math.round(result1);
var result3 = result2 / Math.pow(10, decimals);
return result3.toFixed(2);

}

</script>

</head>

<body>


<form id="order-form">

<table cellpadding="8" align="center">

<tr>
    <td align="left" width="150">Image</td>
    <td align="left">Description</td>
    <td align="left">Price</td>
    <td align="left">Quantity</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="left"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x200"></td>
    <td align="left">Poster</td>
    <td align="left">$24.00</td>
    <td align="left"><input type="number" data-price="24" min="0" max="50" step="1"   value="0" onChange="calculateTotal(this.form)"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="left"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x200"></td>
    <td align="left"> T-shirt</td>
    <td align="left">$66.00</td>
    <td align="left"><input type="number" data-price="65" min="0" max="50" step="1" value="0" onChange="calculateTotal(this.form)"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="left"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x200"></td>
    <td align="left"> Bag</td>
    <td align="left">$120.00</td>
    <td align="left"><input type="number" data-price="120" min="0" max="50" step="1" value="0" onChange="calculateTotal(this.form)"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>TOTAL:</td>
    <td align="right"><input type="text" name="total" size="6" onFocus="this.form.elements[0].focus()"></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the sample code.

```
item_price = form_field.dataset.pric);
```

should probably be

```
item_price = form_field.dataset.price;
```

Apart from that, `NaN` is caused by the fact that you're also taking into account the value of the 'total' field when you run the function `calculateTotal()`. But that field does not have a `data-price` attribute so you're multiplying undefined with a number, resulting in `NaN`.

You need to add an extra check if there is a 'data-price' attribute:

```
function calculateTotal(frm) {
    var order_total = 0;
    for (var i=0; i < frm.elements.length; ++i) {
        form_field = frm.elements[i];

        if(typeof(form_field.dataset.price) != 'undefined') {
            item_price = form_field.dataset.price;
            item_quantity = form_field.value;
            if (item_quantity >= 0) {
                order_total += item_quantity * item_price;
            }
        }
    }
    frm.total.value = round_decimals(order_total, 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.White. Typo wasn't in original code. I made it when typing out question (but point taken). Appreciate your explanation. I understand where I went wrong now.